# Why planet's absorption spectrum works

Tags: absorption

So I've come across this image somewhere on the internet. My understanding of how people determine what's in the atmosphere of distant planets is that the local star (which has a continuous spectrum) shines through the atmosphere of that planet, and we can see dark lines where the atmospheric gases has absorbed. But this image seems to suggest that only atomic oxygen has clear absorption lines, where as molecular oxygen absorbs pretty much everything, but more in some particular wavelengths. If so, do people have to deal with this in their analysis, or is the upper atmosphere of planets have a lot more single atoms than molecules?

[image]

**Edit**:

I came across another image, and here, it shows very sharp absorption lines for molecular oxygen. I'm really confused. So which is the right graph?
[image]

Comment: You can still see bright and dark spots if there are massive peaks just like how we can clearly see peaks in the second spectrum even though it doesn't go to zero.

Comment: @DKNguyen Makes sense. Btw, I just want to confirm the data in the graph looks roughly correct right? Like, it doesn't deviate too much from a lot of other sources?

Comment: Could the top images be logarithmic? I've never really looked into the spectra of individual elements too much since I only care about whether a cloud or water vapour is getting in the way of my sensor and the sun or ground.

Comment: The top graph is labelled as fluorescence and is in the UV. The bottom graph is low resolution and in the IR. What have either of these got to do with exoplanet studies?